# Referring to a cell value in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to refer a cell value, `A1` from `sheet1` in `A1` in `sheet2`.

Usually I'm using the "=" and click on the cell I need!
But, `A1` in `sheet1` is getting its value from a dropdown list with 3 values (ME,YOU,HIM).

What I can do to link both cells, `A1` `sheet1` and `A1` `sheet2` so the value of `A1` `sheet1` will be displayed in `A2` `sheet2`.

Comment: When you say that the source cell is getting its value from a dropdown, do you mean a data validation dropdown, or a combobox object?

Answer (score 0):

Type the reference in the cell on `sheet2` to show the value.

`=Sheet1!A1`